Visual Studio WebBrowser Control issue
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and created a new Windows Forms Project .net Framework
The form is very simple with just one Web Browser Control on it
In the properties of the control under the property URL I added www.kijiji.ca
All I get in the browser is script errors that I click through with the mouse and the page shows up very different then if I just used chrome. Can someone suggest a fix for this plz.
I tried to force the Web Browser control to load a URL on startup.
I expected the URL to load but instead I got many script errors and the page loaded incorrectly compared to chrome or edge

The issue you're encountering with the Web Browser Control is related to the fact that this control uses IE as its rendering engine. By default, it uses an older version of IE, which can lead to script errors and incorrect rendering of modern web pages. Microsoft has introduced a new control called WebView2, which is based on the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) engine. You can install Microsoft.Web.WebView2 on NuGet and use WebView2 control.
